# No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: No filter used or filter was 'null'

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I am trying to implement chat messenger using ejabberd. I am following this tutorial

https://github.com/Shubhank101/iOSAndroidChaosOverFlow-Projects/tree/master/Chat%20Application%20Using%20Xmpp%20Smack%20Api%20Android%20Tutorial

and getting this error

> org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: No response
>   received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter:
>   No filter used or filter was 'null'.

I am not using localhost. I am using live server.